# How to have multiple actions on click of a hyper-link

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a text field accepting item number. On `blur` event am populating the item values, description in other columns.
It is inside a table with previous and next link. When I click on the link, first time the `blur` event happens. Second time only it shows up the next page by calling the `displayNextIcl()` method. How can I make both the events to happen?

Below is the sample code for the textfield and the next hyper-link for pagination.

```
<input type='text' id='itemNumber' maxlength="15"
        onfocus="style.background='#FFF5c7'"
        onkeypress="return numericOnly(this, event);"
        onblur="setICLItemDetails(iclcreateform);style.background='white'"></td>
<a href="#" id='nextLocIcl' class='paginationlink' onclick="displayNextIcl();return false">Next</a></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't understand your question very well, but if you want to make more than one javascript call in your href, define your own function and do all the calls there?

Comment: Basically when I try to navigate to the next page by clicking Next link, it is going to the blur event. Second click only it paginates and takes me to the next page. below is the code for Pagination and textfield  <a href="#" id='nextLocIcl'
      class='paginationlink' onclick="displayNextIcl();return false">Next</a> <input type='text' id='itemNumber' maxlength="15"
      onfocus="style.background='#FFF5c7'"
      onkeypress="return numericOnly(this, event);" 
      onblur="setICLItemDetails(iclupdateform);style.background='white'">